# Call Azure Function (Python) from Data Factory: Response Content is not a valid JObject

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to call a python httptriggered Azure Function from Azure Data Factory. It is the default generated code by Visual Studio code (only added comments). First testing it in Azure Functions in the Azure portal and that works.
[image]

Then in ADF via the Azure Function Activity ([followed instrunctions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-functions-now-supported-as-a-step-in-azure-data-factory-pipelines/))
[image]

But it keeps returning errors: 3603 - Response Content is not a valid JObject
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity, "The return type of the Azure function has to be a valid JObject. (Keep in mind that JArray is not a JObject.) Any return type other than JObject fails and raises the user error Response Content is not a valid JObject". In other words, the Azure Function needs to return JSON as its response rather than the plain string that the generated code returns.